# Ruby on rails Проблема с установкой гема mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysqlconnector

Выдает вот такую ошибку :

```
"D:\RubyMine 2018.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/FLOGmall/Desktop/blo/bit/bin/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e production
Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/vendor/libmysql.dll

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Посмотрел гайды как решается эта проблема, коннектор поставил , старый gem удалил, но все равно выдает ошибку, в чем может быть проблема ? 
Вот на всякий случай gem файл :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.3'
gem 'rails', '>= 4.2.5.1'
gem 'sprockets', '3.5.2'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3'
gem 'papercrop'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'filterrific', github: 'jhund/filterrific'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'axlsx_styler'
gem 'ionicons-rails'
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem "paranoia", "~> 2.0"
gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'
gem 'paper_trail'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.

Учитывая, что ругается на отсутствие библиотеки libmysql.dll, то возможно у Вас не установлен сам mysql2, либо в переменной PATH не прописаны пути к библиотекам.

Comment: Путь к какой именно библиотеке надо прописать  ? К самой mysql2 которая шла вместе с railsinistaler или к конектору ?

Comment: Путь к библиотеке libmysql.dll. Могу ошибаться по вопросу установки гемов mysql и pq  в windos, но для ubuntu предполагается, что в системе уже установлены соответствующие клиенты БД.